# Вывод строки в MATLAB с помощью функции fprintf

Tags: matlab

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста. Я создал матрицу

```
b=250:-50:50
a=linspace(-27,53,5)
w=[a;b]
```

и теперь мне нужно вывести её с помощью `fprintf` с общим заголовком `MatrixW:`. Пытаюсь я делать это таким образом

```
fprintf( 'MatrixW:%d;%d;%d;%d;%d\r\n', w)
```

но таким образом заголовок выводится и в первую, и во вторую строку. Как сделать так, чтобы он был общим? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь есть проблема важнее заголовка: fprintf собирает элементы матрицы **по столбцам**, а не по строкам. Как следствие, матрица

```
-27    -7    13    33    53
250   200   150   100    50
```

выводится как

```
MatrixW: -27;250;-7;200;13
MatrixW: 150;33;100;53;50
```

что вряд ли приемлемо. Следует заменить `w` на `w'`.

По замыслу, команда fprintf формирует и выводит строку раз за разом, пока есть данные для вывода. Поэтому, если заголовок не должен повторяться, его следует выводить отдельно. Например:

```
disp('MatrixW:'); fprintf( '%d;%d;%d;%d;%d\n', w');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
disp('MatrixW:'); 
fprintf( '%d;%d;%d;%d;%d\n', w');
```

это уже костыль получается. мало того что столбцы и строки перепутаны, так еще и писать больше.
когда дано:

```
A=[1 2; 3 4];
B=[5 6; 7 8];
C=A+B;
```

то проще:

```
disp('Сумма А и В:');
disp(B);
```

есть еще вариант как `disp(sprintf('матрица %g %g\n',A));`
но там тоже напутано со строками и столбцами :/